# Иногда при генерации пароля в тг боте вылезает ошибка в терминал

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

Версия aiogram 3.2.0

Ошибка такая: `aiogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: can't parse entities: Unsupported start tag "maox{d?%l*jybqi,$dbr;3!k:)[p wn@i</code" at byte offset 46`

```
import asyncio
import random

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode
from aiogram.filters import Command, CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.client.session.aiohttp import AiohttpSession


TOKEN = "*******************************************"
dp = Dispatcher()


@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def command_start_handler(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Hello I am a bot that generates random passwords To get started, check out the commands\n/start - restart bot\n/generate <b>PASSWORD_LENGTH</b> - creates a unique, random password with a user-specified length.\n/help - shows all commands❓")


@dp.message(Command("generate"))
async def command_generate_handler(message: Message):
    if len(message.text.split()) == 1:
        # Видаємо помилку
        await message.answer("You must specify the password length⚠️\nExample: <code>/generate 12</code>")
        return
    else:
        # Запитуємо довжину пароля
        try:
            length = int(message.text.split()[1])
        except ValueError:
            # Видаємо помилку
            await message.answer("The password length must be an integer number⚠️")
            return

        if length < 8 or length > 48:
            # Видаваємо помилку
            await message.answer("The password length must be specified in the range from 8 to 48⚠️")
        else:
        # Генеруємо пароль
            lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
            upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            numbers = "0123456789"
            symbols = "~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|:;<,>.?/"
            string = lower + upper + numbers + symbols
            password = "".join(random.sample(string, length))

            # Відправляємо пароль користувачу
            await message.answer("Here is your new password: " + f"<code>{password}</code>", parse_mode = ParseMode.HTML)

@dp.message(Command("help"))
async def command_help_handler(message: Message):
    await message.answer("/start - restart bot\n/generate <b>PASSWORD_LENGTH</b> - creates a unique, random password with a user-specified length.\n/help - shows all commands❓")

async def main():
    session = AiohttpSession(proxy="http://proxy.server:3128")
    bot = Bot(TOKEN, session = session, parse_mode = ParseMode.HTML)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: так происходит тогда, когда в сгенерированном пароле попадается символ `<`, так как у вас `parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML`, то телеграм думает, что вы отправляете ему тэг, который он не понимает

Comment: Большое спасибо, ошибка исправилась.